# Anomaly detection in K-means clustering with TF-IDF

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means, anomaly-detection

I have created 4 clusters with all of my text documents using the tf-idf technique. But now I want to do anomaly detection. How would I go about it?

Comment: Your question is too broad for anyone to answer. Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). “Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue. We expect you to make an honest attempt, and then ask a specific question about your algorithm or technique. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: @AlexK I did not find any documentation or tutorial online, hence I write it down here. I dont mind being referred to any tutorial if anyone knows any.

Comment: Check out this meme filled article. https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/tf-idf-term-frequency-technique-easiest-explanation-for-text-classification-in-nlp-with-code-8ca3912e58c3

Comment: @YScharf I get how TF-IDF works and I get how clustering works, but I am wondering how I make calculate anomalies from clusters when I am working with TF-IDF